# Using download attribute with remote file

Tags: html

I'm trying to get the `download` attribute to work on a remote link to image.

Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish:

```xhtml
<a id='image' href='remoteFileName.jpg' download='newFileName.jpg' />
```

So when the link is clicked instead of the browser downloading remoteFileName.jpg, it will save it as newFileName.jpg

I understand the cross origin policy somehow, that it is the reason why this doesn't work. I'm looking for a workaround for this, any ideas?

Comment: download just specifies to download instead of open, and newFileName.jpg is just what its saved "as". What's the issue you're experiencing? is the link to remoteFileName relative?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear but yeah the download tag renaming of the file doesn't work since the href image is hosted on a random image server. @ZachLeighton

Comment: Why can't you just host it yourself?

Comment: What browser are you using? IE and Safari don't support the download attribute. http://caniuse.com/#feat=download

Comment: Hosting the images myself is not an option. The image URL is dynamically collected displayed on my site along with the image. @HarryTorry

Comment: I'm using Firefox primarily but also Chrome. I am aware of the download attributes limitations in its comparability. The only reason I'm attempting to do this is as a quick fix. This is only a weekend project of mine. If there is a better way of renaming a remote image before serving it, let me know. @isherwood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're unable to host the file yourself, you might be able to get around this by having a pass through proxy that you host.  Pass the endpoint a filename and the server could manage the download process and avoid the cross domain hangups.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Could you link me to a resource where I can start looking into this. @gmartellino

Comment: Here's a high level link, but it'll depend on what you'll actually be using to implement it: http://ajaxpatterns.org/archive/Cross-Domain_Proxy.php