# How to change filename when downloading file from server using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am downloading some images from facebook just for learning HTML and JS. But I don't want the filename to be some long string (contains some long string of numbers and chars ).

For eg I am using HTML5 download attribute

```
 <a href="https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xlt1/v/t1.0-9/12109181_503948273111743_2421725301227286538_n.jpg?oh=08c71f2236eaacc243ccd36475b4634e&oe=56BAA86C&__gda__=1459095933_f07fc4bb7bf54f48ac0b9286f8bc92c6"   
  download="imagename.jpg">
  Download Image
 </a>
```

Or this is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/surajpalwe/onj4pkpy/) of above code

When I click this link the file is download but with different name. My question is how do I change the filename something like *images.jpg*

Is it possible? If yes how should I go further.

Comment: No, that's not something you can manipulate on the client side.

Comment: You'll have to rename it after its been downloaded.

Comment: @Amy but when file is downloaded to client side, how could I have access to that dir where the image was downloaded.

Comment: That's not something you can do in a browser.

Comment: @Amy Then how should I go further?

Answer (score 2):

The default filename is sent by the server through HTTP header:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='somefile'
```

Code that runs on the client has very limited control over files for security reasons. The only fix I can see is to have some server code which downloads the file from the other domain and then send it back with a new filename. So no, JS can't fix that for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am relatively sure that the download attribute will only rename files that you are hosting, and not remote files.

You question is similar to this one: 
[Using download attribute with remote file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26511412/using-download-attribute-with-remote-file)

There is a workaround solution mentioned in that answer, but it's probably out of scope for just simple learning exercise.