# Clicking download button to download an image from URL: dots in the URL are all replaced by underscore?

Tags: javascript, html, image, url, button

I'm trying to do this: click a 'download' button and download an image from a URL. Here is my code:

```html
<a download="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/web-links/512/41-512.png" href="" title="ImageName">
  <button>download</button>
</a>
```

Clicking the 'download' button downloads a file with extension .png but some dots in the files is replaced by underscore:

```
https___cdn4.iconfinder.com_data_icons_web-links_512_41-512.png
```

I'd like to have the png downloaded, why does it happen? How can I fix it?

Comment: filenames can't have slashes in them because that would mean a directory, so they get switched to underscores

Comment: Shouldn't the href be the full url and the download just be the filename

Comment: Tried to put the image URL in `href` but it opens the image rather than downloading it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how the `download` attribute works. From MDN:

> If the attribute has a value, it is used as the pre-filled file name
>   in the Save prompt (the user can still change the file name if they
>   want). There are no restrictions on allowed values, though / and \ are
>   converted to underscores. Most file systems limit some punctuation in
>   file names, and browsers will adjust the suggested name accordingly.

So use the `href` attribute to point to the file, and the `download` attribute to, if necessary, specify a filename other than the current one.

```
<a download=my_foo.png href=path/to/foo.png />
```

Comment: Modified my code to `<a download="test" href="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/web-links/512/41-512.png" title="ImageName">`, new problem: clicking the download button opens the image in the browser, rather than downloading it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26511412/using-download-attribute-with-remote-file

Comment: Regarding this previous post, my understanding is: it is unable to download the image from URL due to CORS policy?

Comment: Yeap. Host it locally or use a server-side proxy to pretend it's hosted locally e.g. via PHP cURL.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a):

> This attribute instructs browsers to download a URL instead of navigating to it, so the user will be prompted to save it as a local file. If the attribute has a value, it is used as the pre-filled file name in the Save prompt (the user can still change the file name if they want). There are no restrictions on allowed values, **though / and \ are converted to underscores.** Most file systems limit some punctuation in file names, and browsers will adjust the suggested name accordingly.

So it is in the specs to do so, because in file systems dots and slashes can cause invalid file names.

With your example:

```html
<a download="512.png" href="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/web-links/512/41-512.png" title="ImageName">
  <button>download</button>
</a>
```

Comment: Does your code opens the image in browser rather than downloading it?

Comment: It offers me in Edge a download named `512.png`

Comment: I tested in Chrome, which displayed the image in the browser.